# Add rel="nofollow" to facebook comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, comments

Does somebody know, how we can add the `rel="nofollow"` attribute to all links in the comments plugin from facebook.

```
   <div id ="comments" style="margin-left: 510px; width: 550px" >

         <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://my.net/" data-width="550" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>

        </div>

 </div>


window.addEventListener("load", func, false);

function func() {

  var div = document.getElementById("comments");

 var elements = div.getElementsByTagName("*");

 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
 {



   if (elements [i].tagName == "a") {
     elements[i].rel = "nofollow";
   }

  }


}
```

Array elements do not contain all tags that facebook adds in my .

Comment: Keep in mind that the comments are loaded asynchronously, so you have to change the DOM after the comments loaded, not after your page loaded.

Comment: So, what an action should I use?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (elements[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") 
{
     elements[i].setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
}
```

And you must paste your code after FB init, not on window.load.

Comment: Array elements do not contains all tags that facebook add in my <div class="fb-comments">

Comment: Please **explain** what you changed and why.

Comment: I try to add attribute "rel = nofollow" in comments to all tags "a".

Comment: @Makedonsky, yes, because all links will be added AFTER FB init. Where is init in your code?

Comment: I understood that I need to add a special event handler, because there "document.onload" doesn't work. How do I know which event handler to use?